# Not able to fetch HTML element inside javascript function, but is fetches the attributes of that element

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a simple code where am trying to validate name field and in case it is invalid, I will make the label adjacent to it visible and display the error there.

the Javascript function is:

```
function ValidateName(id) {
    var error = "";
    var illegalChars = /[^a-zA-Z ]/; // allow alphabets and whitespace only
    var labelId = "";

    if(id=="fromName")
      labelId="lblFromName";
    else
      labelId="lblToName";

    if (id.value == "") {   
        error = "Please enter the name\n";
        document.getElementById(labelId).hidden=false;
        document.getElementById(labelId).innerHTML=error;
        id.style.borderColor="#dd4b39";
        return false;
    } else if (illegalChars.test(id.value)) {
        error = "Contains illegal characters\n";
        alert(error);
        document.getElementById(labelId).hidden=false;
        document.getElementById(labelId).innerHTML=error;
        id.style.borderColor="#dd4b39";
        return false;
    } else if ((id.value.length < 3) || (id.value.length > 35)) {
        error = "Please enter atleast 3 characters\n";
        alert(error);       
        document.getElementById(labelId).hidden=false;
        document.getElementById(labelId).innerHTML=error;
        id.style.borderColor="#dd4b39";
        return false;
    } 
}
```

This code is not working... I tried to debug a lot and found that when i try to alert just id, it shows object HTMLInputElement; but when i try to print id.placeholder, it successfully prints as Name. Can you please tell me what wrong am i doing here?

Thanks

Comment: what is id in ValidateName(id) ??????

Comment: it is getting called by the following:   <input NAME="fromName" TYPE="text" id="fromName" placeholder="Sender's Name" style="width:200px;" value="<?php echo $fromName;?>" MAXLENGTH="35" autofocus onBlur="ValidateName(fromName)">

Comment: check my answer and code will go like this onBlur="ValidateName('fromName')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

**CASE 1**

HTML CODE

```
    <input id="my_txt" type="text" value="ABC" onchange="ValidateName(this)">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function ValidateName(obj){
    obj.id // will give you  my_txt
    obj.value // will give you ABC
}
```

**CASE 2**

HTML CODE

```
<input id="my_txt" type="text" value="ABC" onchange="ValidateName(this.id)">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function ValidateName(id){
    id //will give you my_txt
    id.value // will give you ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `onBlur="ValidateName(fromName)"`

You are passing the *variable* `fromName`, when your code is expecting a *string*.

Add quotes to change it to:

```
onBlur="ValidateName('fromName')"
```